# SOAP Service call breaking ignores try catch

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I've got a dll that relies on a SOAP call to a web service, and I was provided with the WSDL file from the vendor, and after some testing, I've got code that will successfully call the service and get the response with no issue.  However, when the vendor moved the service to a new server, my code starting failing.

Specifically, I get a `NullRefernceException` that, even though it is square in a try/catch block, ignores all of that and crashes anyway.

my call looks like this:

```
new ChannelFactory<GRChannel>(binding, address).Using(async(factory) =>
            {

                factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "TestUser";
                factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "1234";

                var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

                proxy.Open();

                var context = new OperationContext((IClientChannel)proxy);

                var prevOpContext = OperationContext.Current;
                OperationContext.Current = context;
                try
                {
                    var results = await proxy.ZBAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATEAsync(payload); //<-- Null happens here
                    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(ZBAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATEResponse));
                    using (StringWriter text = new StringWriter())
                    {
                        
                         serializer.Serialize(text, results.ZBAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATEResponse);
                         Message = text.ToString();
                    }                    
                }
                catch
                {
                    //Nothing here matters, we never make it to this point
                }
            });
```

the Stack Trace is this at the time of failure:

```
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at RFCDLL.RFC.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<RunRequest>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\User01\source\repos\RFCDLL\RFCDLL\RFC.cs:line 46
```

obviously, having a null failure is fine, and expected when the service isn't running, I just want to make sure the error handling works, and I can not have the whole app crash when that happens.

Comment: `catch { throw; }` is going to re-throw the original exception. Are you expecting something else to happen?

Comment: I Simpilfied for brevity, but regardless, it never makes it into the catch statement. it fails at the arrow